# PHP email data feed problem

Tags: php

Hi I am trying to get a data feed from a vendor. I set up a page and gave them a URL and told them to httppost csv data.

right now my page just looks like this so I can see what the data looks like that I am getting:

```
$feedData = file_get_contents("php://input");

mail('myemail@gmail.com','data feed from vendor',$feedData);
```

They said they sent me some test data, I checked my email and I got the email but it was blank. I am not sure if I did something wrong or they did.

What should be my next step to trouble shoot this?

Thanks!

Comment: please specify how and what they "send" and how you receive it.

Answer (score 1):

HTTP POST data should be present in `$_POST`. You should first check that this superglobal contains any data. If not, data are not being correctly POSTed to your URL.

You are right to test by having data emailed to yourself, however this can be problematic with non-string types. You need to be certain that `$feedData` is a string and contains data.

Examining the type and content of a variable is straightforward when combining var_dump() with output buffering. Try:

```
ob_start();
var_dump($_POST);
$testDump = ob_get_contents();
ob_end_clean();

mail('user@example.com', 'data feed from vendor', $testDump);
```

Testing process:

1. POST *anything* to your URL and check that the resulting email contains the correct data.
   If the resulting email is not as you expect, the fault lies with your code. Work with the code until the test email contains what you expect given the data you POST.
2. Ask the vendor to POST their data
   Examine the resulting email and see if it matches what you expect. If not, check with the vendor as to the nature of the data they are sending - perhaps your understanding or expectations are wrong. Repeat until you get the correct content in the test email.

From examining the content of the test email, you can determine the elements within $_POST that are relevant to your needs, extract them as necessary and continue development.

At the point when your test email does contain what you expect, note the $_POST contents such that you can construct an identical POST request which you can use when continuing development.

Answer (score 0):

check what kind of `$feedData` you're using and whether it conforms to the [requirements](http://docs.php.net/manual/en/function.mail.php). My guess is that it doesn't.

Answer (score 0):

http post data should be in $_POST['var'];

try this:

```
mail('myemail@gmail.com','data feed from vendor',var_export($_POST, true));
```

Comment: Hi I tried this too, and had them try again. I got the email empty again. All they have is a URL and they are supposedly sending me a feed to the URL. I think they are doing a server to server post but I am having sort of a communication barrier with them. THANKS

Answer (score 0):

Are you uploading a file and reading it with php://input?, since php://input does not work with multipart/form-data

Answer (score 0):

You could also try to filter and read http packets via [Wireshark](http://www.wireshark.org/), if you are hosting the receiving part yourself.